# How to customize the APK file name for product flavors?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I am customizing the **name of the APK** file of my Android application within the `build.gradle` script as follows:

```groovy
android {
    defaultConfig {
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "MyApplication");
    }
}
```

Now that I am using product flavors:

```groovy
android {
    productFlavors {
        green {
            applicationId "com.example.myapplication.green"
        }

        blue {
            applicationId "com.example.myapplication.blue"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to customize the name of **each APK**? I experimented with `archiveBaseName` and `baseName` without success. In the end I want to come up with the following files:

```
build/outputs/apk/Blue-debug-1.2.1.apk
build/outputs/apk/Blue-debug-unaligned.apk
build/outputs/apk/Blue-release-1.2.1.apk
build/outputs/apk/Blue-release-unaligned.apk
build/outputs/apk/Green-debug-1.2.1.apk
build/outputs/apk/Green-debug-unaligned.apk
build/outputs/apk/Green-release-1.2.1.apk
build/outputs/apk/Green-release-unaligned.apk
```

Answer (score 28):

Try to put this in your android closure of build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        // debug buildType specific stuff
    }
    release {
        // release buildType specific stuff
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("release") &&
            variant.productFlavors[0].name.equals("green") &&
            variant.zipAlign) {
                def apk = variant.outputFile;
                variant.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, "green.apk");
        } else if(variant.buildType.name.equals("release") &&
            variant.productFlavors[0].name.equals("blue") &&
            variant.zipAlign) {
                def apk = variant.outputFile;
                variant.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, "blue.apk");
        }
    }
}
```

Now the outputs should be like `green.apk` and `blue.apk`.

Comment: Why do you check the product flavor name if you do the same for both "freeflavor" and "proflavor" anyways? What I really want is to change the "Modulename" as in your example - not appending something.

Comment: Still: what is the reason you have two `if` blocks as I asked before?

Comment: Yes. It is not serving much purpose here and can be further simplified.

Comment: The if statement rounded brackets are not complete... Although even putting them there has no impact for me

Comment: This didn't work, missing paren and apparently incompatible with the Android plugin? I was getting an error about undefined attribute outputFile. See my answer below that shows how I fixed it.

Comment: Is there any solution for .aab file?

Answer (score 27):

This will help you in 2022.

```
android {
    
//........
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    Free {
        dimension "version"
        applicationId "com.exampleFree.app"
    }
    Paid {
        dimension "version"
        applicationId "com.examplePaid.app"
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def appId = variant.applicationId// com.exampleFree.app OR com.examplePaid.app
        def versionName = variant.versionName
        def versionCode = variant.versionCode // e.g 1.0
        def flavorName = variant.flavorName // e. g. Free
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name // e. g. debug
        def variantName = variant.name // e. g. FreeDebug

        //customize your app name by using variables
        outputFileName = "${variantName}.apk"
    }
}}
```

Apk name **FreeDebug.apk**

**Proof**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not working for me, it does nothing. I added a "println outputFileName" and it is printing correctly, but for some reason gradle is not using the "outputFileName" value for the file name. By the way, I'm trying to use it for an app bundle, not an APK.

Comment: Does not work when you use Bundles in 2021.

Comment: Works great with APK.

Comment: Is there any solution for .aab file?

Answer (score 10):

For Android Gradle Plugin 0.13.+ you should use something like this:

```
android{
    buildTypes {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def apk = output.outputFile;
                def newName = "mysms-" + variant.baseName.replace("-release", "") + "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk";
                output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has stopped working in Android Gradle 3.0.0-alpha1. You can no longer access the outputFile it seems.

Comment: Really useful if you don't want to update your gradle version!

Answer (score 10):

For Android Studio 3.0 you must change from:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, "whatever.apk")
    }
}
```

To:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { 
            outputFileName = "whatever.apk"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I did it like this:

```
productFlavors {
        production {
            applicationId "com.example.production"
        }

        staging {
            applicationId "com.example.production.staging"

        }

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                if(variant.productFlavors[0].name.equals("staging")){
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                            output.outputFile.name.replace("app-staging-release",  "test"));

                }else{
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                            output.outputFile.name.replace("app-production-release",  "production"));
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is **outputFile**??

Answer (score 3):

It's weird that you would need this because the apk filename **is already different** by default.

If you look [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.groovy) at line 1346, you can see that the variantData.variantConfiguration.baseName is used in the outputFile.

```
variantData.outputFile = project.file("$project.buildDir/apk/${project.archivesBaseName}-${variantData.variantConfiguration.baseName}.apk")
```

And the documentation for `baseName` is

```
/**
 * Full, unique name of the variant, including BuildType, flavors and test, dash separated.
 * (similar to full name but with dashes)
 */
private String mBaseName;
```

So running `gradle assembleFreeDebug` should get you a `ProjectName-free-debug.apk` file.

But if that isn't the case, or you want a different filename, you can use the following code to customize it.

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {}
        alpha {}
        release {}
    }
    productFlavors {
        free{}
        paid{}
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def newApkName = variant.name + "my-custom-addition" + ".apk";
        variant.outputFile = new File("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/", newApkName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost there. (1) For some reason the `-unaligned.apk` files in `build/outputs/apk` still carry the `MyApplication` prefix. (2) The variant is not capitalized.

Comment: Any idea how to complete this?

Comment: (1) According to line 1316 in the BasePlugin.groovy-link, you can change the `project.archivesBaseName` and `variantData.variantConfiguration.baseName` to adapt the unaligned-outputname. But I'm note sure if this will mess with other build-steps. Still, you shouldn't be using the unaligned-version, but rather the final apk (of which you can fully control the apk-name).

(2) variant.name.capitalize()

Answer (score 3):

Here's my variant (heh) of Lakshman's answer above, not sure why I needed the "variants.outputs.each" but I did.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.company.com"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.productFlavors[0].name.equals("VariantA")) {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def apk = output.outputFile;
                output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, "Blue.apk");
            }
        } else { // Only two variants
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def apk = output.outputFile;
                output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, "Green.apk");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ……

        // custom output apk name
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "${variant.productFlavors[0].name}-${variant.buildType.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
            }
        }
    }
    ……
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

Add the `variant.productFlavors[0].name` in the APK name.

Code example:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, "APPNAME_" + variant.productFlavors[0].name + "_" + variant.versionName + ".apk")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every answer here is the same, and outdated. It's easy to do [flavor]-[version]-[build type]:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        green {
            applicationId "com.example.myapplication.green"
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", "Green-" + defaultConfig.versionName)
        }

        blue {
            applicationId "com.example.myapplication.blue"
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", "Blue-" + defaultConfig.versionName)
        }
    }
}
```

If your versionName is "1.2.1", running gradle assemble will produce:

*Green-1.2.1-debug.apk*

*Green-1.2.1-release.apk*

*Blue-1.2.1-debug-apk*

*Blue-1.2.1-release.apk*

Answer (score 0):

Android Gradle Plugin 0.13.0 has deprecated the outputFile that is used in:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def newApkName = variant.name + "my-custom-addition" + ".apk";
    variant.outputFile = new File("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/", newApkName);
}
```

The solution that is working for me is:

```
android {
... 
}

project.archivesBaseName = "AndroidAppGeneric-${_buildVersionNameForMaven}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following so the files won't override each other:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def newApkName = variant.name + "-" + variant.versionName + "(" + variant.versionCode +")" + ".apk";
        output.outputFile = new File("${project.projectDir}/outputs/apk/" + variant.name, newApkName);
    }
}
```