# Type org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d is defined multiple times (but only on release, not debug)

Tags: android, opencv, gradle

In my Android application, I have both imported the OpenCV library, as well as integrated a [live edge detection](https://github.com/adityaarora1/LiveEdgeDetection/tree/a32a3db35880ef286427315cba7ca318bbdc4178) library, which in turn uses OpenCV on its own.
Originally, this created a conflict between the two versions of OpenCV, but I was able to resolve that.

I am now trying to do a production release for the first time since this change, and I am encountering the following error during my release build (in the mergeDex...Release stage):

```
Type org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d is defined multiple times: .../OpenCVSDK/build/.transforms/73aaad4d2991f9ad7ec3aa9b43023dc9/transformed/release/org/opencv/calib3d/Calib3d.dex, .../app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/prodSbirRelease/mergeExtDexProdSbirRelease/classes3.dex
```

Why is this suddenly an issue now, with a release build, when it was (and continues to be) fine with debug builds? And how can I fix it?

Here is my app build.gradle:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('.../ReleaseKeyStore')
            storePassword '...'
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword '...'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('.../ReleaseKeyStore')
            storePassword '...'
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword '...'
        }
    }
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 3
        versionName "0.9.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        // Based on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-default-generated-apk-name-in-android-studio/
        // and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104323/how-to-customize-the-apk-file-name-for-product-flavors
        applicationVariants.all{
            variant ->
                variant.outputs.each{
                    output->
                        def name = "ImageCapture-${variant.flavorName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                        output.outputFileName = name
                }
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "environment", "product"
    productFlavors {
        local {
            dimension "environment"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "LOCAL Image Capture"
        }
        dev {
            dimension "environment"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "DEV Image Capture"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "environment"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Image Capture"
        }

        sbir {
            dimension "product"
        }
        nci {
            dimension "product"
        }
    }

    androidComponents {
        onVariants(selector().all(), { variant ->
            switch (variant.name) {
                case "localSbirDebug":
                case "devSbirDebug":
                case "localSbirRelease":
                case "devSbirRelease":
                    variant.applicationId = "ai.dlanalytics.imagecapture.dev"
                    break
                case "prodSbirDebug":
                case "prodSbirRelease":
                    variant.applicationId = "ai.dlanalytics.imagecapture"
                    break
                case "localNciDebug":
                case "devNciDebug":
                case "localNciRelease":
                case "devNciRelease":
                    variant.applicationId = "ai.dlanalytics.imagecapture.nci.dev"
                    break
                case "prodNciDebug":
                case "prodNciRelease":
                    variant.applicationId = "ai.dlanalytics.imagecapture.nci"
                    break
            }
        })
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/*.so'
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/DEPENDENCIES', 'META-INF/LICENSE', 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt', 'META-INF/license.txt', 'META-INF/NOTICE', 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt', 'META-INF/notice.txt', 'META-INF/ASL2.0', 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module']
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        mlModelBinding true
    }
    namespace 'ai.dlanalytics.imagecapture'

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.adityaarora1:LiveEdgeDetection:master-SNAPSHOT'


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.32.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.2.0-alpha01"

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0"
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'

    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0'

    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"

    implementation project(path: ':OpenCVSDK')
//    implementation 'org.bytedeco:opencv:4.5.5-1.5.7'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-modeldownloader'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.3.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

And my project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:0.10.5'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm relatively new to Android builds, so please let me know what other helpful information I can provide.

Comment: In the error message you see both locations, try to find out why they are there. One is OpenCvSDK the other one in app/build/intermediates ...

Comment: @Micka - it seems that one is coming from my imported OpenCV, while the other is coming from the imported edge detection library (com.adityaarora.liveedgedetection). If I comment out any references to that second library, the build succeeds. But of course then my app is missing that functionality.

Comment: not sure about android, maybe there is a solution or maybe you will have to use the exact same build that was used in the edge detection library (or build the edge detection library from scratch with your wanted opencv version/build).

Comment: how did you resolve your original conflict (to get the debug build working)?

Comment: I commented out `implementation 'org.bytedeco:opencv:4.5.5-1.5.7'` in app/build.gradle (see above).